# Class footer not found

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap v3.3.4. 
I want to implement a footer in my web page. But, it doesn't work.

The code of my page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Web site</title>
    <link href='css/main.css' rel='stylesheet'>

    <!-- Library -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Bootstrap/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="Script/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Script/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='container'>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center">
                <h2><b> My first web site!</b></h2>
                <div style="padding-bottom: 10px;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row well">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">                    
                <p>This is my first web site, I'm trying to learn Bootstrap.</p>
                <button type='button'>Take the Tour</button>
                <button type='button'>Book Tickets Now</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                <img src="Images/universe.jpg" alt="Blasting Off"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row well">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                <h3><b>I am 20 years old!</b></h3>
                <p>I was born in 1994.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                <h3><b>I live in Rome!</b></h3>
                <p>Rome is a beautiful city.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                <h3><b>I am a programmer!</b></h3>
                <p>I am a front-end developer, I started to do this work recently.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <p class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

NetBeans says **Class footer not found**

I have included **bootstrap.min.css** and **bootstrap-theme.min.css**

If I open the page with a browser (Chrome, im my case) the footer doesn't work..

Why? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you're trying to import a footer from the twitter-bootstrap library. Unfortunately twitter-Bootstrap does not include a default CSS for a footer class. (It might do for the HTML-tag , but there is no class).

Depending on what kind footer you want to display there are some examples over at http://www.getbootstrap.com

For example:
http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/

Hope that helped you.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly what you are asking for but this may help.

If you want the footer to be fixed at bottom, then try adding this to your CSS code.

**CSS:**

```
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
 }
```

I hope this will help you?